# Web application deployed to remote Tomcat instance using IntelliJ cannot find JNDI resource (javax.naming.NameNotFoundException)

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea, jndi

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 14.0.2 to launch a local Tomcat 7.0.42 instance and then to separately deploy a WAR using a remote Tomcat run configuration. My web app fails to acquire a resource through JNDI and I suspect it is because it fails to remotely connect to JMX, although the WAR is deploying without issues if I comment out the JNDI lookup. If I include the Tomcat launch and WAR deployment in the same local Tomcat run configuration, the lookup works fine.

Here are all the details that I think are relevant, please let me know if you want anything else. Thanks for your help!

### Local Tomcat Run Configuration:

*HTTP port:* 8080

*JMX port:* 11444

*JAVA_OPTS*

```
-Dcatalina.base="C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.42"
-Dcatalina.home="C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.42"
-Dwtp.deploy="C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.42\wtpwebapps"
-Djava.endorsed.dirs="C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.42\endorsed"
-Depf.config.root="C:/dev/appConfig"
-Dactivemq.conf="C:/dev/appConfig/app-common-config/environment/dev-win/activemq"
-Dactivemq.data="C:/dev/activemq"
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=11444
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dwebconsole.type=properties
-Dwebconsole.jms.url=tcp://localhost:61616
-Dwebconsole.jmx.url=service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:11444/jmxrmi
-Dwebconsole.jmx.user=system
-Dwebconsole.jmx.password=password
-Dlog4j.configuration=file:C:\dev\appConfig\logging\log4j.xml
-Djava.util.logging.config.file="C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.42\conf\logging.properties"
-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
-Djava.security.auth.login.config="C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.42\conf\jaas.config"
-Xms2048m
-Xmx2048m
-XX:NewSize=512m
-XX:MaxNewSize=512m
-XX:PermSize=512m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

*CATALINA_OPTS*

```
-Dactivemq.conf=C:/dev/appConfig/app-common-config/environment/dev/activemq
-Dactivemq.data=C:/dev/appConfig/activemq-data 
-Dlog4j.configuration=file:C:/dev/appConfig/logging/log4j.xml
-Djava.security.auth.login.config=C:/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/conf/jaas.config
```

### Remote Tomcat Run Configuration:

*JMX port:* 11444
*Remote staging:* Same file system
*Host:* Same file system

*Remote Connection Host:* localhost
*Remote Connection Port:* 8080

*Deployment:* my-web:war

### catalina.properties

```
## JMS Connection Factory
JMS.connectionFactory.factoryName=jms/jms.connectionFactory
JMS.connectionFactory.auth=Container
JMS.connectionFactory.brokerName=ActiveMQBroker
JMS.connectionFactory.brokerURL=tcp://localhost:61616
JMS.connectionFactory.factory=org.apache.activemq.jndi.JNDIReferenceFactory
JMS.connectionFactory.type=org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory
JMS.connectionFactory.typeInterface=javax.jms.ConnectionFactory

## Local JMS Queue
JMS.queue.auth=Container
JMS.queue.name=jms/my.queue
JMS.queue.physicalName=my.queue
JMS.queue.factory=org.apache.activemq.jndi.JNDIReferenceFactory
JMS.queue.type=org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue
```

### context.xml

```
<ResourceLink global="${JMS.connectionFactory.factoryName}" name="${JMS.connectionFactory.factoryName}" type="${JMS.connectionFactory.typeInterface}"/>
    <ResourceLink global="${JMS.queue.name}" name="${JMS.queue.name}" />
```

### server.xml

```
<Resource auth="${JMS.connectionFactory.auth}"
        brokerName="${JMS.connectionFactory.brokerName}" brokerURL="${JMS.connectionFactory.brokerURL}"
            description="JMS Connection Factory" factory="${JMS.connectionFactory.factory}"
            name="${JMS.connectionFactory.factoryName}" type="${JMS.connectionFactory.type}" />

    <Resource auth="${JMS.queue.auth}" description="Outbound Queue"
        factory="${JMS.queue.factory}" name="${JMS.queue.name}"
        physicalName="${JMS.queue.physicalName}" type="${JMS.queue.type}" />
```

### localhost:8080/manager/text/resources

```
OK - Listed global resources of all types
jms/jms.connectionFactory:org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory
jms/my.queue:org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue
UserDatabase:org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabase
```

### JNDI lookup

```
@Bean(name = {"jndiObjectFactory"})
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
@Profile("default")
public JndiObjectFactoryBean jndiObjectFactory() {
    JndiObjectFactoryBean jof = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
    jof.setResourceRef(true);
    jof.setJndiName("jms.connectionFactory");

    Properties jndiProps = new Properties();
    jndiProps.put("java.naming.factory.initial", "org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory");
    jof.setJndiEnvironment(jndiProps);

    return jof;
}
```

### The error

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class 

org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'TestController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.me.test.factory.TestFactory com.me.test.tester.web.controller.TestController.testFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'TestFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jndiObjectFactory' defined in class path resource [com/me/test/SpringConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jms.connectionFactory] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jms.connectionFactory].
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1551)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:622)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:569)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1487)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:97)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1328)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1420)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:848)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:556)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:811)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:670)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.me.test.factory.TestFactory com.me.test.tester.web.controller.TestController.testFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'TestFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jndiObjectFactory' defined in class path resource [com/me/test/SpringConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jms.connectionFactory] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jms.connectionFactory].
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'TestFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jndiObjectFactory' defined in class path resource [com/me/test/SpringConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jms.connectionFactory] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jms.connectionFactory].
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:407)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1017)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:960)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
    ... 58 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jndiObjectFactory' defined in class path resource [com/me/test/SpringConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jms.connectionFactory] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jms.connectionFactory].
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:205)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:991)
    at com.me.test.factory.TestQueueFactory.newInstance(TestQueueFactory.java:45)
    at com.me.test.factory.TestFactory.createEmitter(TestFactory.java:178)
    at com.me.test.factory.TestFactory.readConfigurationFromPropertiesFile(TestFactory.java:155)
    at com.me.test.factory.TestFactory.init(TestFactory.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:133)
    ... 70 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jms.connectionFactory] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jms.connectionFactory].
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:820)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:168)
    at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:158)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate$1.doInContext(JndiTemplate.java:155)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.execute(JndiTemplate.java:87)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:152)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:179)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorSupport.lookup(JndiLocatorSupport.java:104)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectLocator.lookup(JndiObjectLocator.java:106)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.lookupWithFallback(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:231)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:217)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
    ... 86 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just a dumb mistake on my part and I'm not sure why it was working as a local tomcat run configuration before. I went back to trying it that way and I got the same error.

It was simply because the JNDI name should be "jms/jms.connectionFactory" when I was trying to lookup just "jms.connectionFactory".